# Mechanical Turk API : HIT creation, i get an error when the Qestion field is not provided

Tags: mechanicalturk

i'm trying to create a HIT using Mturk Api (javascript version), in the documentation the "Question" field is not required, but if i leave it empty, i get an error ? is it due to some updates or new versions ?
can someone help me please ? did someone faces the same issues ?

Thank's

Answer (score 2):

The Question parameter is required unless you use a HITLayout[1] (using the HITLayoutID and HITLayoutParameter fields)

The Question is where you define the user interface the Workers will use to complete your HIT. You can define it by passing in HTML/CSS/JavaScript in an HTMLQuestion[2], using our QuestionForm XML schema[3], or by embedding your own page within the HIT in an IFRAME using ExternalQuestion[4].

Instead of passing in one of these Question types, you can pass in the HITLayoutID and HITLayoutParameters to use a layout that you generate in a Project on the Requester website. For more information, please refer to the HITLayout documentation[1].

I hope this helps.

Please let us know if you have any additional questions.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_HITLayoutArticle.html

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_HTMLQuestionArticle.html

[3] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_QuestionFormDataStructureArticle.html

[4] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_ExternalQuestionArticle.html

Comment: first of all, thank you for your response,
let me explain you my need in more details. 
"The Question is where you define the user interface the Workers will use to complete your HIT." in my case the 'Question' is a frontend (React.js app).
How can this be done, i create a HIT using Mturk API and let the workers that select my HIT use my react app to complete the HIT.

1- the worker select the HIt.
2- (my react app) will be rendered in a new tab in the browser.
3- the worker complete and submit the finished task.

thank you
Best